# Is there a way to set my default as the number of seconds since 1970?

Tags: sql-server

In my tables I am setting a current date/time as:

```
 [ModifiedDate]  DATETIME         DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
```

But is there a way that I could set this to the number of seconds since 1970. The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970

I realize I will need to have this field as an integer but I am not sure how to set the default value?

Comment: Ask DATEDIFF() with 01-01-1970?

Comment: What does "number of seconds since 1970" mean? If you mean unix time, say unix time. If you don't, explain what *exactly* do you need. E.g. how should DST, leap seconds etc. be treated? And why do you want to *store* the integer, rather than storing the `datetime` and converting it to whatever representation you need in your application?

Comment: But how can I include a DATEDIFF in a default ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I really would suggest it's better to store `datetime2` value or even `datetime`, you can simply use Alex K's suggestion:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    UnixTime int DEFAULT(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01 00:00', GETDATE())),
    CreateDate datetime DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)
```

Test:

```
INSERT INTO @T DEFAULT VALUES

SELECT *
FROM @T
```

Result:

```
UnixTime    CreateDate
----------- -----------------------
1468930170  2016-07-19 12:09:30.380
```

Another option, as Damien_The_Unbeliever suggested, is to use a computed column:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    CreateDate datetime DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    UnixTime as DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01 00:00',CreateDate)
)
```

Comment: I'd probably have `UnixTime` as a computed column instead, if it's only used for reading from (and then it's always consistent with `CreateDate`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I Agree. added that to my answer. thanks.